# mapping dataframes not series pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, series

I am new to pandas, and I am trying to map multiple columns as opposed to just one. [This page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) shows me how to do it with a `pd.Series`, but I cannot figure out how to map multiple `columns`.

Here is my two `DataFrames` I am trying to `map`.

```
data2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),index=range(0,5),columns=['x','y'])
data2['Cluster']=['A','B','A','B','C']
centers2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,2)),index=  ['A','B','C'],columns=['x','y'])
```

Here `data2` looks like:

```
data2

   x         y              Cluster
0  0.151212 -0.168855       A
1 -0.078935  1.933378       B
2 -0.388903  0.444610       A
3  0.622089  1.609730       B
4 -0.346856  1.095834       C
```

and `centers2` looks like:

```
centers2
   x  y
A  6  4
B  6  0
C  4  1
```

I wish to create two seperate columns in `data2`, with the appropriate `center2` matching. Here is my manual attempt

```
data2['Centers.x']=[6,6,6,6,4]
data2['Centers.y']=[4,0,4,0,1]
data2
          x         y Cluster  Centers.x  Centers.y
0  0.151212 -0.168855       A          6          4
1 -0.078935  1.933378       B          6          0
2 -0.388903  0.444610       A          6          4
3  0.622089  1.609730       B          6          0
4 -0.346856  1.095834       C          4          1
```

How can I do this with the `map` function? (I know how to do this using loops, I need a vectorized solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.merge()` comes closest to `pd.Series.map()` for `pd.DataFrame`. You can add a custom header to overlapping columns using the `suffixes=[]` keyword, for instance `suffices=['', '_centers']`.

Note `pd.Series` doesn't have `.merge()`, and `pd.DataFrame` doesn't have a `.map()`.

With

```
data2
          x         y Cluster
0 -1.406449 -0.244859       A
1  1.002103  0.214346       B
2  0.353894  0.353995       A
3  1.249199 -0.661904       B
4  0.623962 -1.754789       C

centers2
   x  y
A  0  9
B  6  9
C  0  6
```

You get:

```
data2.merge(centers2, left_on='Cluster', right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_centers']).sort_index()

          x         y Cluster  x_centers  y_centers
0 -1.406449 -0.244859       A          0          9
1  1.002103  0.214346       B          6          9
2  0.353894  0.353995       A          0          9
3  1.249199 -0.661904       B          6          9
4  0.623962 -1.754789       C          0          6
```

There is also the `.join()` option, which is another way to access `.merge()`, or `pd.concat()` if `.merge()` is on `index` for both `DataFrame` - from the source:

```
def join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',
         sort=False):
    return self._join_compat(other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix,
                             rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)

def _join_compat(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',
                 sort=False):
    from pandas.tools.merge import merge, concat

    if isinstance(other, Series):
        if other.name is None:
            raise ValueError('Other Series must have a name')
        other = DataFrame({other.name: other})

    if isinstance(other, DataFrame):
        return merge(self, other, left_on=on, how=how,
                     left_index=on is None, right_index=True,
                     suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
    else:
        if on is not None:
            raise ValueError('Joining multiple DataFrames only supported'
                             ' for joining on index')
```

Comment: Yes, it is easiest, but sorting is changed.

Comment: That's right, added `.sort_index()` to make sure that gets sorted.

Comment: Would love to - where is it?

Comment: The source code suggests that if the second instance is a `DataFrame`, `.join()` calls `.merge()`. No surprise timing is the same! If it's not a `DataFrame`, it converts it to one. If it's a merge on `index` only, it calls `pd.concat()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
print pd.concat([data2.x, data2.y, 
                 data2.Cluster, 
                 data2.Cluster.map(centers2.x.to_dict()), 
                 data2.Cluster.map(centers2.y.to_dict())], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=['x','y','Cluster','Centers.x','Centers.y'])

          x         y Cluster  Centers.x  Centers.y
0 -0.247322 -0.699005       A          6          5
1 -0.026692  0.551841       B          1          4
2 -1.730480 -0.170510       A          6          5
3  0.814357 -0.204729       B          1          4
4  2.387925 -0.503993       C          1          0
```

Solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html): [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index)

```
print data2.join(centers2, on='Cluster', rsuffix ='_centers')

          x         y Cluster  x_centers  y_centers
0 -0.247322 -0.699005       A          6          5
1 -0.026692  0.551841       B          1          4
2 -1.730480 -0.170510       A          6          5
3  0.814357 -0.204729       B          1          4
4  2.387925 -0.503993       C          1          0
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is same as `join`, but `2` parameters are added:

```
print data2.merge(centers2, 
                  left_on='Cluster', 
                  right_index=True, 
                  suffixes=['', '_centers'], 
                  sort=False, 
                  how='left')
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=5k`:

```
data2 = pd.concat([data2]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

def root(data2, centers2):                  
    data2['Centers.x'] = data2.apply(lambda row: centers2.get_value(row['Cluster'], 'x'), axis=1)
    data2['Centers.y'] = data2.apply(lambda row: centers2.get_value(row['Cluster'], 'y'), axis=1)                  
    return data2

In [117]: %timeit root(data2, centers2)
1 loops, best of 3: 267 ms per loop

In [118]: %timeit data2.merge(centers2, left_on='Cluster', right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_centers'], sort=False, how='left')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

In [119]: %timeit data2.join(centers2, on='Cluster', rsuffix ='_centers', sort=False, how='left')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

In [120]: %timeit pd.concat([data2.x, data2.y, data2.Cluster, data2.Cluster.map(centers2.x.to_dict()), data2.Cluster.map(centers2.y.to_dict())], axis=1, keys=['x','y','Cluster','Centers.x','Centers.y'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop

In [121]: %timeit data2.merge(centers2, left_on='Cluster', right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_centers']).sort_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop
```

Comment: Added timeit of `Stefan Jansen` solution.